# How to change the default Folium marker?

Tags: python, visualization, folium

[image]

```
folium.Marker([float(lat), float(lon)], popup=f"<i>{location}</i>", tooltip=tooltip, 
        icon=folium.Icon(color="red",icon="bus-simple", prefix='fa')).add_to(m)
```

How could I do that the marker just shows the bus icon and not the red background?

Answer (score 1):

To show only the bus icon without the red background in a folium map, you can modify the `folium.Icon` call to use the `icon_color` parameter instead of the color parameter.

```
folium.Marker([float(lat), float(lon)],
              popup=f"<i>{location}</i>",
              tooltip=tooltip, 
              icon=folium.Icon(icon="bus-simple", icon_color="white", prefix='fa')
             ).add_to(m)
```

The icon_color parameter sets the color of the icon, while leaving the background transparent. In this case, I set it to "white" to match the default color of the bus icon. You can adjust the color to your preference.